# Neighborhood and derivates

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the solution set of the equations
$$2x + y + 2z + u − v − 1 = 0$$
$$xy + z − u + 2v − 1 = 0$$
$$yz + xz + u^2 + v = 0$$
(a) Show that, in a neighborhood of (1, 1, −1, 1, 1) the variables x, y and z can be put into terms of u and v.
(b) Calculate thecv of the function from the previous part at the point (1, 1).

Comment: Can you clarify what is the order of variables in the "neighborhood"?

Comment: Sorry, that's all the information I have, I feel confused and didn't know how to ask

Comment: Is this relevant: [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)? Also, what is "the cv"/"thecv" of the function? (Does it have something to do with Jacobian matrix?)